# Remember previously open files when launching Visual Studio Code to edit a file

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I launch Visual Studio Code directly it remembers all the files I had open previously. The issue I have is if I (under Win10) right click a file and select "Open With Code". If VS Code *is already open* everything is file. If VS Code is *not* open, it will launch and open the file, **but forget all the files I had previously opened**.

This seems like unexpected (and non-consistent) behavior. Is there a way to get VS Code to launch from "Open With Code" but have it also open all the files I had opened previously? Basically, act the same as if VS Code was already opened when I clicked on "Open With Code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to your setting.json (Code Menu > Preferences > Setting)

`"window.restoreWindows": preserve`

[This issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/14675) seems to cover exactly your case and has been resolved [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15949)